# B&Q type navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

on B&Q's newly designed website if you hover over Shop in the navigation then Paint, Wallpaper & Decorating you get another menu appear to the right. I would like to do something similar but looking at the code in dev tools I cant workout how this final menu appears? Is it via CSS or JS? could anyone give me pointers on recreating a similar style navigation?

Edit: link to website - http://www.diy.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use inspect element in that page and discover it how it is made
or use F12 to toggle the inspect menu

Comment: Try reading what I already put " I would like to do something similar but looking at the code in dev tools I cant workout how this final menu appears?"

Comment: try investigate the bootstrap approach there are lots of styles that toggle on :hover to show or hide content and it is pure css

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a mix of CSS and JS, after inspecting the menu it looks like a class `.is-active` is being added to the parent element i.e. 'Paint, Wallpapers...' then CSS is set up which styles the child element on hover. I think JS is removing the class again on mouseout.

So basically it's just swapping the hidden menu from `display: none` to `display: block` on hover

Comment: Not sure it is just doing that as the hidden menu is set to be off  the screen (-999em) so just displaying it would not show it on the screen.

Comment: yep offsetting it -999em is another way of hiding it, essentially doing the same thing and getting the same effect